# Set default value to a model(Sails.js)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterlock

I am starting to learn Sails.js and I want to know if there is a simpler way to set the default value in a model from a session variable? I am using **Waterlock** to do authentication and setting the user_id in a session variable like `req.session.user_id`. I have a message model, I want to default the `'from'` field to this session variable. Is there a way to do this in Sails.js?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sail's default ORM, *Waterline*, then model attributes have a *defaultsTo* option. The supplied value may be a function. You can look at the [waterline documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/data-types-attributes.md).

**Sample Model**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    description: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: 'No description.'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    alias: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: function(){
        return this.email;
      }
    },
  }
};
```

If the supplied value is a function, then the call to this function is bound to the values in the create.

For `Model.create(values)...`, if alias is null/undefined, then `alias = defaultsTo.call(values)` is used to get the value for alias.

So to use `req.session.user_id` you may have to include it during create.
`Model.create({session: req.session,...})`. I am not really sure, since I do not use Waterlock. And I'm not don't think this is the best way to go about it.

From my experience these extra values are ignored when using adapters such as *sails-mysql*, but if you are using *sails-disk* for development, then you might see that these extra values are persisted. You may want to delete them before you persist.

```
  beforeCreate: function(values, cb){
    delete values['session'];
    cb();
  }
```